# Javascript viewport then element.style.left wont work? whats wrong with this

Tags: javascript, width, viewport

```
    var x,y,a,b;
    function respon(){
    x= Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth,window.innerWidth||0);
    y=document.getElementById("main");
    b=x-1200;
    a=y.style.left= b/2+ "px";
}

window.addEventListener("scroll",parallex,respon);
```

I want to center div element with width 1200px.

I wanted to take viewers width - 1200, then divide that by 2, and thats my margin-left, and the object is centered :) (my target screen size were 1980)

(I would use "if statement" later,but if this is not working, I dont need it )

I want to know, whats wrong with this, and why is this not working ?
For me everything looks fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are setting `margin-left`,instead of `left` you must do it like this:

`a=y.style.marginLeft= b/2+ "px";`

If you want to stick with the `left`, you must add

`a=y.style.position = "relative";`